# Cannot Select Item in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I created a navigation bar in android and I am unable to select an item. I want to display a toast when a specific item is selected but it doesn't enter into the if condition of checking id of the item clicked.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (abdt.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.addCat) {
            Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Category Name Field is Empty!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: `onOptionsItemSelected` returns `true` if and only if the specified item is handled. I suggest that you should either remove the condition that checks against whatever the `abdt` variable is, or invert the condition.

Answer (score 0):

In Navigation Drawer to implement item selection, you need to implement the interface of `NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.addCat:

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Category Name Field is Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               break;        
          }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    }
```